# What available Wi-Fi dongles support AP mode?

Tags: wifi, wireless, ubuntu

I would like to use my laptop as a Wi-Fi hotspot, but the Wi-Fi hardware does not support AP mode, which I understand is required, as mentioned [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) and other similar pages providing instructions for how to set it up.

With a google search I did find [this](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) page, but there is just a '?' in the column for whether the dongle supports AP mode or not.

Do you have a Wi-Fi dongle that supports AP mode? If so, what is it?

If it matters, I am running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You don't want that page, you want [this one](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers).

Comment: @Mark And how do we read that page? Personally, I’m about to ask the same question (except Ubuntu 16.04 — but I expect OP to have that, too, by now) so I’ld love an answer …

Comment: @Jan, you go down the "AP" column to find something that says "yes", then click on the driver to get a list of chipsets it supports, and select a wifi device with one of those chipsets.